# Remove structured data from Woocommerce single product pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, structured-data

I am trying to remove the `structured data` that Woocommerce adds to the product pages.

I did some research and found that `WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()` generates the structured data markup. It's hooked in the `woocommerce_single_product_summary` action hook in the `woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php` template file.

I tried by adding the following code to the `functions.php`

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data()', 60 );
```

So structured data wouldn't be added by Woocommerce, **but it doesn't work**…

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, you can use dedicated filter hook `'woocommerce_structured_data_product'` that is located in [`WC_Structured_Data`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Structured_Data.html) for [`generate_product_data()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Structured_Data.html#265) nulling the structured data output in single product pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'structured_data_product_nulled', 10, 2 );
function structured_data_product_nulled( $markup, $product ){
    if( is_product() ) {
        $markup = '';
    }
    return $markup;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect people want to remove the default tabs and they come here after they see the Woocommerce `content-single-product.php` template. In this template you see that `generate_product_data()` is hooked with priority 60.

After inspecting the hooks that run on `woocommerce_single_product_summary`.

You can easily remove the tabs with:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );
```

I think Woocommerce forgot to mention this add_action.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can remove hooks associated with instantiated object method. You have to find the variable that holds the new Object instance.

In this case the main WooCommerce object is accessible as `$GLOBALS['woocommerce']` and it has public property `$structured_data` which holds an instance of the WC_Structured_Data object.

Hence, to remove the hook in the question you can write this code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', array( $GLOBALS['woocommerce']->structured_data, 'generate_website_data' ), 30 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', [$GLOBALS['woocommerce']->structured_data, 'generate_product_data'], 60);   
});
```

Unhooks WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data(). Will not waste resources on generating product data first for no reason and then "nulling" that same generated data a moment later using a filter.